# Searching by key in Apache CouchDB

Tags: php, couchdb, nosql

Is it possible to search by key value in Apache CouchDB?  Given the sample data below (spaced for readability):

```
{
    "_id":"a754a63dcc7f319b02f7ce6de522ca26",
    "_rev":"1-5bd88e53fe0869b8ce274b49a2c1ddf5",
    "name":"john smith",
    "email":"jsmith@example.com",
    "username":"jsmith"
}
```

Could I query the database for the user jsmith or for the user having the email jsmith@example.com?  How would I go about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that is certainly possible. You will create a couple of views, which are sorted lists ("index") of your data, one per key.

Tobias's link is useful. However the standard CouchDB documentation will cover this also:

- [Finding your data with views](http://books.couchdb.org/relax/design-documents/views) in the book (I prefer this resource)
- [Introduction to CouchDB views](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views) in the wiki

For example, in your design document, you might want a `users_by_email` view, with keys based on the `email` field; then a `users_by_name` view keyed on the `username` field, etc. Experiment with the temporary views in Futon until you get your function working just right, and then store it in your design document permanently.

Good luck!

P.S. There is a way to combine all of these requirements into one view. Briefly, you could key on `["email", "jsmith@example.com"]` or `["name": "john smith"]` however remember, CouchDB is relaxed: The simpler method above will work fine. When you become comfortable with views, you can explore this "collated" style.

Comment: fyi - keys should be short because keys get saved within every object. i always try to keep em really small like "email" would be "m" or "e" - "username" would be "u"...

just an fyi - nobody has to do it but if you store a lot of data it helps saving some space.

Answer (score 2):

http://sitr.us/2009/06/30/database-queries-the-couchdb-way.html

Answer (score 2):

You cannot search by a keyvalue. You can only search by keys.

If you want to search for emails, emit [email, whatever data] in some view and add `?key='search email'` to view url.

Searching only by keys gives huge performance benefits and hence this feature [searching by key value] will never ever come to couchDB.